# Do not populate while tabbing - bootstrap-datetimepicker by Eonasdan

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

In regards to the Eonasdan datetimepicker:

If I have multiple fields with datepickers and separate time pickers, as I tab through the fields (which I need to do) the date or time picker will pop up and as I tab to the next field will populate the text input with the current date and the time of 0:00 (I am using 24 hour time).

Is there a way to stop this behavior and require the value to actually be clicked on to populate the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a stupid question but if you use the option useCurrent: false it will not insert the value into the text field. Oddly, when useCurrent is true I do not get the current time so was confused by the functionality of this option.